# add non permanent vectors to data frame using rbind

Tags: r

i've non permanent vectors that i like to merge them to one data frame,

im using the following loop to create those vectors

```
for (i in campagin_id){
h <- basicHeaderGatherer()
doc <- getURI(paste0(automations_url,
                     "/",i,
                     "?apikey=",accessToken,
                     "&count=",pagination), headerfunction = h$update)

assign(paste0('web_id',i),c(i,as.integer(substring(h$value()[as.integer(grep(SearchTerm, h$value()))],
                             as.integer(regexpr(SearchTerm,h$value()[as.integer(grep(SearchTerm, h$value()))]))+nchar(SearchTerm)-1,as.integer(regexpr(SearchTerm,h$value()[as.integer(grep(SearchTerm, h$value()))]))+nchar(SearchTerm)+StringLength-2))))
}
```

i received list of vectors and i like to marge them with rbind something like that

```
rbind(web_id0f09cc8ddd,web_id18a71f70a8)
```

the issue is that i don't not how many vectors i will get but i knows only the beginning of the vector name, so i'm trying to run the following loop

```
for (i in campagin_id) {
web_id <- do.call("rbind",list(paste0('web_id',i)))
}
```

but it insert only one vector to the data frame

the campaign_id contains all the i values i need in specific time

Thanks

Comment: There's a style guide in SO that includes capitalization as well as no "Thanks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do.call` is the right idea, but `rbind` is a slow operation. You should add your vectors to a list one-at-a-time, and then do a single `rbind` at the end, something like this (untested, obviously, as the example isn't reproducible, but it should give you the idea):

```
result_list = list(length = length(campagin_id))
for (i in campagin_id) {
    h <- basicHeaderGatherer()
    doc <- getURI(
        paste0(
            automations_url,
            "/",
            i,
            "?apikey=",
            accessToken,
            "&count=",
            pagination
        ),
        headerfunction = h$update
    )

    result_list[[i]] = c(i, as.integer(
        substring(
            h$value()[as.integer(grep(SearchTerm, h$value()))],
            as.integer(regexpr(SearchTerm, h$value()[as.integer(grep(SearchTerm, h$value()))])) +
                nchar(SearchTerm) - 1,
            as.integer(regexpr(SearchTerm, h$value()[as.integer(grep(SearchTerm, h$value()))])) +
                nchar(SearchTerm) + StringLength - 2
        )
    ))
}

results = do.call(rbind, result_list)
```